# The code is supposed to transform every letter of every word to uppercase. But running the code results in a bus error. What causes the bus error?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, if-statement, while-loop

The code is supposed to transform every letter of every word to uppercase. But running the code results in a bus error. What causes the bus error?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *ft_strupcase(char *str)
{
    int index;

    index = 0;
    while (str[index] != '\0')
    {
        if (str[index] >= 97 && str[index] <= 122)
            str[index] = 65 + str[index] - 97;
        index++;
    }
    return (str);
}
int main()
{   
    char *name = "sEbas";
    printf("%s\n", ft_strupcase(name));
    return (0);
}
```

Input: sEbas

Output: SEBAS

Comment: What does stepping through the code in the debugger show you?

Comment: FWIW: +65-97 = -32 (as is more customarily used).

Comment: @user2864740 yeah, I changed to **90** + str[index] - **122** or **65** + str[index] - **97** thank you all !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string "sEbas" is a `const char[]`, so you shouldn't use it to initialize `char* name`.

If you compile this code on Visual Studio 2019, it won't compile and will tell you the error:

`cannot convert from 'const char [6]' to 'char *'`

You can replace it with:

`char name[] = "sEbas";`